# PyQtGraph - Turn off perspective in 3d view

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, pyqtgraph

I'm using PyQtGraph to plot mesh surfaces. I would like to see the 3D world with perspective turned off.

Is this possible in pyQtGraph? I have searched through the documentation and the google groups and can't find any reference to this. I think it is possible in principle with openGL so is there a way to bring this out and control perspective on/off in pyQtGraph?

Comment: Are you asking for orthographic projection instead of perspective  projection ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok. Here is the code.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = gl.GLViewWidget()
w.setBackgroundColor('k')

# Switch to 'nearly' orthographic projection.
w.opts['distance'] = 2000
w.opts['fov'] = 1

# set-up title grid etc...
w.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example')
g = gl.GLGridItem(color='w')
w.addItem(g)

# insert draw commands here.

w.show()

## Start Qt event loop
QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

A cursory inspection of the docs renders no help ... however if you decrease the field of view (FOV) while also increasing the distance you will approximate an orthographic projection to arbitrary precision as you vary those two parameters

Comment: how would you do this in code? I can see that it works in principle after several attempts at scrolling/zooming etc...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying out the newer vispy; it is much more flexible with regards to the types of cameras and mouse interactions supported. In particular, orthographic projection happens to be the default for the 'arcball' camera type, and probably the others too; it's set by setting camera.fov to be 0.

As a bonus, ergonomics with ipython are also much improved, i.e. your ipython shell stays responsive at the same time the scene is active, and you can kill the scene without killing your ipython instance, and launch another.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I've looked for the same thing recently and wanted to give a different solution.

PyQtGraph doesn't expose this directly, but it can be achieved by subclassing the `GLViewWidget` and overriding the `projectionMatrix` method (see [GLViewWidget source](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.html#GLViewWidget) and [qt docs for QMatrix4x4](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html#ortho)).
For example, the following sets the projection to 'ortho' by default, with the option to switch to perspective (frustum) projection:

```
def projectionMatrix(self, region=None, projection='ortho'):
    assert projection in ['ortho', 'frustum']
    if region is None:
        dpr = self.devicePixelRatio()
        region = (0, 0, self.width() * dpr, self.height() * dpr)

    x0, y0, w, h = self.getViewport()
    dist = self.opts['distance']
    fov = self.opts['fov']
    nearClip = dist * 0.001
    farClip = dist * 1000.

    r = nearClip * np.tan(fov * 0.5 * np.pi / 180.)
    t = r * h / w

    ## Note that X0 and width in these equations must be the values used in viewport
    left = r * ((region[0] - x0) * (2.0 / w) - 1)
    right = r * ((region[0] + region[2] - x0) * (2.0 / w) - 1)
    bottom = t * ((region[1] - y0) * (2.0 / h) - 1)
    top = t * ((region[1] + region[3] - y0) * (2.0 / h) - 1)

    tr = QtGui.QMatrix4x4()
    if projection == 'ortho':
        tr.ortho(left, right, bottom, top, nearClip, farClip)
    elif projection == 'frustum':
        tr.frustum(left, right, bottom, top, nearClip, farClip)
    return tr
```